# Does a vector space over $F$ necessarily contain a field isomorphic to $F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a question I had and answered myself, and I didn't find this anywhere on Google so I thought it would be interesting to share. Initially posted this in Math Overflow but deleted that question because users notified me that it didn't fit there, but I still thought it was an interesting question so I'm putting it here again.

By definition, a vector space $V$ over $F$ is the tuple $(V, F, \cdot)$ where $F$ is a field, $(V, +)$ is an abelian group, and $\cdot: V \times F \rightarrow V$ satisfies associativity, distributivity, and compatibility with the multiplicative identity in $F$.

I always thought of vector spaces as a generalization of field extensions, but upon reflection I couldn't actually prove using the definition that $V$ must contain something isomorphic to $F$. If I think about vector spaces like $F^n$ and any ring extension over $F$, it seems almost 'obvious' that $V$ should contain something isomorphic to $F$. Or am I just missing a counterexample?

Answer (score 13):

This is actually a bit more subtle than your answer suggests.

Let $V$ be a (nonzero!) $K$-vector space and $v\in V$ a nonzero vector. The subspace $Kv$ of scalar multiples of $V$ is in obvious bijection $b$ with $K$ itself. But is this bijection an **isomorphism**?

The issue is that, while $Kv$ does have a built-in notion of *addition* $+_V$ which $b$ respects - this is just saying that $\alpha v+_V\beta v=(\alpha+_K\beta)v$, where $+_K$ is the scalar addition of $K$ - it does not come with a built-in notion of *multiplication*. Properly speaking, we can only say that $Kv$ is a **group** which is isomorphic to **the additive group of** $K$ itself.

But this *also* isn't the whole story. We do have a "mixed-type" operation in our vector space, namely *scalar multiplication*. This is a map $\cdot_V: K\times V\rightarrow V$ rather than $V\times V\rightarrow V$, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether it "lines up" with the multiplication $\cdot_K$ of $K$ itself under $b$, but there's a natural way to fudge this: just "leave the left coordinate unchanged." The fact that $$\alpha\cdot_V(\beta v)=(\alpha\cdot_K\beta)v$$ then says that things do in fact line up nicely. I suspect this is what you have in mind; however, since this isn't literally a multiplication-of-vectors which we're passing through $b$, it's not quite true to say that $Kv$ is isomorphic to $K$ as fields. Instead, $Kv$ and $K$ are isomorphic as ... $K$-vector spaces!

Comment: Ah I see (also minor typo but I think you meant "the subspace $Kv$ of scalar multiples of $v$"). But why can't we do this?: We have a vector space $Kv$ contained in $V$, which has algebraic properties like addition and scalar multiplication. Now define a multiplication between two elements of $Kv$ to be one where we just pass through the scalar. Under addition and this new multiplication, this is now a field isomorphic to $K$. So $V$ contains something that can be made to be isomorphic to $K$. (?)

Comment: $Kv$ under this new multiplication still inherits all the operations of $V$, so it's not like we're arbitrarily defining new operations on a subset of $V$. So $Kv$ is a $K$-vector space, and also a field. And we can see $V$ as extending $Kv$ just without that multiplication, just like how a commutative ring extension $R$ of $K$ extends $K$ just without the multiplicative inverses. (?)

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite true; the only thing we can say is that a vector space over $F$ contains a vector space isomorphic to $F$, as an $F$-vector space.

Original approach: First, suppose that $V$ is not the zero vector space. Then take any nonzero vector $v \in V$. Consider the set of all scalar multiples of $v$, $av$ for all $a \in V$ (span v). This is a set contained in $V$ which is isomorphic to $F$. You can use the distributivity and associativity axioms to show that this is true.

Why this isn't quite true: $V$ does not have any notion of multiplication, so it doesn't really make sense to take a subset of $V$ and give it another operation—even though there is a natural candidate for multiplication here which is to just ignore $v$.